# Tabela flutuando para nova página

Tags: latex

Olá,

Estou tentando ajustar uma tabela para que ela fique na mesma página da seção que foi criada para comportá-la, entretanto, por mais que seja uma seção de página vazia com apenas esta tabela, esta passa automaticamente para uma nova página deixando a anterior em branco.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,fleqn]{repUERJ}                           
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite} 
\usepackage[font=default,frame=no]{repUERJformat}                                             
\usepackage[maxfloats=25]{morefloats}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{placeins}`
```

Minha tabela:

```
\begin{table}[h] {12cm}
    \centering
    \caption{Variáveis e Fontes dos Dados}
    \label{Variáveis e Fontes dos Dados}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \textbf{Variável}                                                                                                                                               & \textbf{Fonte} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{I  }                                                                                                             & SEV           \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{P }                                                                                                                              & IBGE           \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A}                                                                                                                         & IBGE           \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}T = Intensidade Energética\\ O\end{tabular}} & IBGE e BEN     \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Já tentei demais variações de opções do pacote `float`, tal como o `[H]`, porém não alterou essa questão.

OBS: Estou usando a template repUerj disponível [aqui](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bpqdkmgxznvh#/11388571/)

Comment: se for imprescindível tenta `\begin{table}[h!]`

Answer (score 0):

Experimente eliminar o segundo carregamento de `placeins` em

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{placeins}
```

Talvez isso tenha apagado a opção `section` da primeira chamada. Se não funcionar, esperimente forçar antes da seção com '\FloatBarrier'

```
\begin{table}
....
\end{table}

Algum texto finalizando a seção.

\FloatBarrier

\section{próxima seção}
```

Mas eu recomendo usar esse tipo de coisa apenas no final. Deixa a tabela e figuras flutuar nos rascunhos. Normalmente o LaTeX encontra uma posição melhor do que as que eu imagino. Apenas em textos muito curtos eu preciso forçar a posição da figura.

Se nada disso ainda der certo, você não precisa deixar a tabela flutuar. Retire o tabular de dentro de `table` e use `\captionof`.

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \captionof{table}{Variáveis e Fontes dos Dados}
  \label{Variáveis e Fontes dos Dados}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{I} & SEV \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{P} & IBGE \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A} & IBGE \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}T = Intensidade Energética
                        \\ O\end{tabular}} & IBGE e BEN \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Marcos. Já tentei também essa sua sugestão, mas continua a mesma coisa. A tabela segue indo para a outra página deixando a anterior em branco. Conhece algo mais que eu possa tentar?

Comment: A única coisa que eu consigo imaginar agora é: usar parte do texto e da tabela com problema em um arquivo separado, sem usar o pacote da `repUERJ`. Talvez seja algo interno desse pacote que esteja conflitando com o `placeins`.

Comment: Também pode experimentar carregar o `placeins` antes de `\usepackage[font=default,frame=no]{repUERJformat}`.

Comment: Também acho que pode ser algo com o pacote em questão, pois em outros pacote, sempre consegui organizar tabelas e imagens somente com o `float`. Achei interessante essa sua sugestão de usar parte do texto e da tabela em um arquivo separado. Você tem algum material que explique o modo de realizar isso?

Comment: Nessas horas eu recorro a força bruta, mesmo. Troco '\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,fleqn]{repUERJ}' por '\documentclass[a4paper]{report}' e chamo o pdflatex. Mas como você deve ter muita coisa que depende do `repUERJ`deve gerar muito erro. Por isso eu sugeri copiar parte do texto. Sinto muito, nada muito inteligente. Espero que esteja usando um controle de versão como o git. Ajuda a reverter experiências como essa, se derem errado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção, Marcos.